# How to keep temporary _main.Rmd file in bookdown (when there is no error)

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am building a PDF from several RMarkdown files using Bookdown in Rstudio. In the process, Bookdown first compiles the different Rmd files into one big Rmd file (_main.Rmd), and then knits it into a PDF. If no errors are thrown, this temporary _main.Rmd file is usually deleted. I would like to keep the _main.Rmd file even when the file has successfully knitted into a PDF.

Is there any option I can add to _bookdown.yml to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I just added](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/fd8dac6029f460591791d4cfbbad9da1bc4314b1) this feature in the development version of **bookdown**, you may try:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```

and set `delete_merged_file: false` in [the config file `_bookdown.yml`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html).